# Side-loading multiple app versions of the same solution in the same device

Tags: visual-studio-2015, deployment, uwp, windows-10-mobile

My UWP app is distributed by sideloading it through all the mobile devices. Now we need to have multiple versions (development, test and production) of the same app installed simultaneously in the same device.

I tried this:

1. Deploy the app
2. Change package and app names in the manifest
3. Deploy again

In the second deploy I get **Error DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009287**

Is it even possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can have 3 versions of the same app on the machine at one time.  I think you will have to have different names for the dev and test versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not enough to change package name in the Package.manifest but also generate a new certificate pfx file.

After doing this, we managed to deploy multiple instances of the same solution.